# Overlapping discount issue ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, overlapping, discount

```
 getLoanType(type) {
        return Util.convertToEmptyString(type) !== '' && (type.toLowerCase() === 'intro' || type.toLowerCase() === 'fixed') ? 'Fixed' : 'Variable'
}

 getDiscount(amount, type) {
        const loanType = this.getLoanType(type)
        let discountRate = 0
        this.discountTypes.forEach((discountType) => {
            if (discountType.type.toLowerCase() === loanType.toLowerCase()) {
                // we have the right discount type now get the discount
                discountType.discounts.forEach((discount) => {
                    if (discount.discount < 0) {
                        // find negative discount rate for the loan amount/lvr
                        if ((amount >= discount.lowerLimit) && (amount <= discount.upperLimit) && (this.lvr >= discount.lvrLower) && (this.lvr <= discount.lvrUpper)) {
                            discountRate = discount.discount
                        }
                    } else if (
                        discount.lowerLimit <= amount &&
                        discount.upperLimit > amount &&
                        discount.lvrLower <= this.lvr &&
                        discount.lvrUpper >= this.lvr
                    ) {
                        // Apply max possible discount (overlapping ranges)
                        if (discount.discount > discountRate) {
                            discountRate = discount.discount
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        return discountRate
    }
```

below is my discounts and discountTypes array

```
discounts: [
  {
    "uniqueId": "66b1ae80-9046-4aa2-afa0-f6bf8dea1c41",
    "lowerLimit": 15000,
    "upperLimit": 999999999,
    "discount": 0.1,
    "lvrLower": 0,
    "lvrUpper": 70
  },
  {
    "uniqueId": "a3fc7d03-78a1-427e-bba3-90f5fc43b9d8",
    "lowerLimit": 15000,
    "upperLimit": 999999999,
    "discount": 0,
    "lvrLower": 70,
    "lvrUpper": 80
  },
  {
    "uniqueId": "419b6a56-0f1f-4287-b84d-204d4589f4b8",
    "lowerLimit": 15000,
    "upperLimit": 999999999,
    "discount": -0.3,
    "lvrLower": 80,
    "lvrUpper": 95
  }
]
```

```
discountTypes
[
  {
    "uniqueId": "2789c4bf-9919-4918-82cc-ecd131a8b197",
    "productId": "5731bbcb-5b10-4980-8c61-68c503490106",
    "state": "All",
    "type": "Variable",
    "discounts": [
      {
        "uniqueId": "e1916541-53e6-4279-9178-d80117de931b",
        "lowerLimit": 15000,
        "upperLimit": 999999999,
        "discount": 0,
        "lvrLower": 0,
        "lvrUpper": 95
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uniqueId": "5b7512a7-10d8-406d-907b-af203289dd9a",
    "productId": "5731bbcb-5b10-4980-8c61-68c503490106",
    "state": "All",
    "type": "Fixed",
    "discounts": [
      {
        "uniqueId": "c7478e14-ef80-4f3a-8d2b-da9a2a0a1b14",
        "lowerLimit": 15000,
        "upperLimit": 999999999,
        "discount": 0.1,
        "lvrLower": 0,
        "lvrUpper": 70
      },
      {
        "uniqueId": "7cda1897-1480-40a9-bb2d-777abdf93295",
        "lowerLimit": 15000,
        "upperLimit": 999999999,
        "discount": 0,
        "lvrLower": 70,
        "lvrUpper": 80
      },
      {
        "uniqueId": "4f547011-1221-4544-9b98-00b729c36c9f",
        "lowerLimit": 15000,
        "upperLimit": 999999999,
        "discount": -0.3,
        "lvrLower": 80,
        "lvrUpper": 95
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can anyone help in fixing the overlapping issue, for LVR = 80, it should apply discount of 0% as per discount array, but its applying discount of -0.3% which falls under LVR range of 80-95 which is incorrect.

I have tried changing to below

```
if ((amount >= discount.lowerLimit) && (amount <= discount.upperLimit) && (this.lvr < discount.lvrLower) && (this.lvr < discount.lvrUpper))
```

it fixed the issue of LVR =80, and applying correct discount of 0%, but now I am facing issue with LVR = 81, its applying discount of 0% which is incorrect, it should have applied 80-95 discount range of -0.30%.